# Java: Tangent method

Tags: java, math

What is the opposite of the `Math.tan(double x)` function of java?

I know that `Tan(X) = oppositeSideLength/AdjacentSideLength`

but I have the opposite and adjacent sides so I want to do the opposite operation.

ie: `x = Tan^-1(oppositeSideLenght/AdjacentSideLength)` (that is how I would enter it in a calculator.

I just looked in the [Math class](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) and I know that there is:

- `Math.atan(`
- `Math.atan2`

but I don't think that either of these is what I am looking for.

Comment: Why not? They are *both* what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you do indeed want atan, or sometimes, atan2. The difference between the two is that atan will fail under some circumstances when one of the side lengths are zero. While that may be unlikely for triangles, it is a possibility for some other, more general uses of atan. In addition, the atan function gives you an angle limited to the interval [-pi/2,pi/2]. So if you think about the atan function as a function of two inputs, (x,y), atan(y/x) will yield the same result as atan((-y)/(-x)). This is a serious flaw in some circumstances.

To solve these problems, the atan2 is defined such that it yields the correct result for all values of x and y, in any quadrant. One would use it as

```
atan2(oppositesidelength,adjacentsidelength)
```

to yield a consistent result.

Of course, for use in a non-degenerate triangle, the simple call to atan(opposite/adjacent) should be entirely adequate for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you want `atan`, the arc tangent. This is the inverse of tangent; same thing with sin and arc sine, cosine and arc cosine, etc. These are alternative mathematical terminology for these functions' inverses.

Notice how `atan` returns angles from -π/2 to π/2, by the way. That's a hint that it's an inverse function (tangent takes angles and spits out ratios, arc tangent takes ratios and spits out angles). It is also important to recognize the restricted range. You won't necessarily get back your original angle, since tangents repeat every π radians (every 180°) — tan(π) = 0, but atan(0) = 0, not π.

Answer (score 2):

Math.atan is indeed the opposite of tangent. It's called [arctangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Basically x = arctan(tan(x)). Well, it's a tad more complex than that seeing that tangent is a repetitive function (it needs some adjustments by adding k*pi). You should check out the wikipedia article about the details.

Anyway, you can indeed compute x (the angle) by doing `Math.atan(opposite/adjacent)`. Take note though that the angle will be in radians, so make sure you convert to other units if that's not what your using.

Answer (score 2):

Math.atan and Math.atan2 should work just fine.

```
angle = Math.atan(Math.Tan(radians));
angle = Math.atan(oppositeSideLength/adjacentSideLength)
angle = Math.atan2(oppositeSideLength, adjacentSideLength)
```

Comment: I don't think atan2 is what he needs. According to wikipedia: For any real arguments x and y not both equal to zero, atan2(y, x) is the angle in radians between the positive x-axis of a plane and the point given by the coordinates (x, y) on it. It's a different angle from the one in the triangle.

Comment: atan2 WILL be correct. However, it is not necessary. As I said in my response, atan will be sufficient.